# How to set default values for Preferences in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application and I need to set some values in the preference page as defaults when the RCP run as an application. I need to hide the Fast View bar and some menus from a certain peresepective that is why I need to set these settings from the preference page.

My application is not a product yet, so I cant use the plugin_customization.ini file to change in it.

Can anyone tell me a way to change the default values programmatically via the preference page or any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the extension point `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences`

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
         <scope name="SamplePreferencePage" class="com.example.SamlePreferencePage"/>
      <initializer
            class="com.example.PreferenceInitializer">
      </initializer>
  </extension>
```

Comment: I used this extension point but I didnt know the preference name to set its value when I used setValues(String PreferenceName, Boolean value)

Comment: If I want to make Hide Fast View Bar boolean by true what should I write as PreferenceName?

Comment: It's your application's preference; you can call it whatever you want.  Call it "HideFastViewBar".

Comment: you can also see the example of stracka. For every field you give an StringID. With the same string you can retrieve the the values from the PreferenceStore.

Answer (score 11):

Define extension points for your **preference page**, and for that page's **initializer** class:

An example preference page implementation might look like:

```
public class MyPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {
    public static final String PREF_USE_METRIC_UNITS = "PREF_USE_METRIC_UNITS";
    public static final String PREF_AUTO_UPDATE = "PREF_AUTO_UPDATE";
    public static final String PREF_USER_FILES_DIR = "PREF_USER_FILES_DIR";
    public static final String PREF_FAVORITE_ANIMAL = "PREF_FAVORITE_ANIMAL";

    public MyPreferencePage() {
        super(GRID);
    }

    public void createFieldEditors() {
        Composite parent = getFieldEditorParent();
        addField(new BooleanFieldEditor(PREF_USE_METRIC_UNITS, "Use &metric units", parent));
        addField(new BooleanFieldEditor(PREF_AUTO_UPDATE, "&Auto update", parent));

        addField(new DirectoryFieldEditor(PREF_USER_FILES_DIR, "User files &path:", parent));

        addField(new StringFieldEditor(PREF_FAVORITE_ANIMAL, "Favorite &animal:", parent));
    }

    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setPreferenceStore(Plugin.getPlugin().getPreferenceStore());
    }
}
```

You then set the actual default values in your AbstractPreferenceInitializer class:

```
public class MyPreferenceInitializer extends AbstractPreferenceInitializer {
    @Override
    public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {
        IPreferenceStore store = Plugin.getPlugin().getPreferenceStore();

        store.setDefault(MyPreferencePage.PREF_USE_METRIC_UNITS, true);
        store.setDefault(MyPreferencePage.PREF_AUTO_UPDATE, false);

        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String defaultPath = userHome + "\\Local Settings\\Temp\\";
        store.setDefault(MyPreferencePage.PREF_USER_FILES_DIR, defaultPath);

        store.setDefault(MyPreferencePage.PREF_FAVORITE_ANIMAL, "platypus");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your answer is extending mine, I'll give you an +1 ;)

Comment: I like the code samples provided. But the phrasing "Define extension points for your preference page" is a bit ambiguous. It appears there are actually 2 extensions points that could qualify (org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences or org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages). The answer would be better if you exactly named the extension point. Luckily I found the answer to that part of the question in the answer by @aphex. I guess its good both answers are somewhat complementary in providing a complete picture :-)